# Is there a twitter functionality to be selective with retweets?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

At times, there are tweets that I would deem appropriate to retweet to specific lists or only to certain followers. I've had much experience using Twitter and third party programs like Tweetdeck but it seems like a broad brush is painted when it comes to retweets, it's either all or nothing. Is there something I haven't looked into and "specific retweeting" exists?

Comment: I don't think Twitter is really designed for that.  You can do that with Google+ or Facebook though.  Twitter is best for sharing things publicly (unless they added functionality since I last used it, which was admittedly a long time ago).

Comment: Also, that doesn't sound like functionality that could be implemented by a third party program... the twitter API and data model would have to be changed for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The API to posting a tweet (or re-tweeting) does not allow a target.

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid